# Evento ao click não acontece (onclick ) NextJS

Tags: javascript

index.js:

```js
function Home () {
    return <div>
        <html>
       
 <head>
<title>Site</title> 
</head>


<body>
 
 
 <div class= 'v5_3' onclick = "funcao_click()"></div> 


 </body>
    
        </html>
        
        </div>
    
    }
    
function funcao_click() {
   
   
    alert('VOCÊ CLICOU NA IMAGEM!');


        }
        export default Home ; funcao_click
```

Estou desenvovendo localmente com o nextjs atraves do `npm run dev` que eu aprendi [por esse link (19:00 ate 21:50)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EW7m2WIvFgQ) porem quando eu clico no botão que ta dentro da div 'v5_3' que por sua vez esta no arquivo main.css:

```
.v5_3 {  
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(5, 5, 5);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 1171px;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  
  
}
```

, que esta sendo importado pelo arquivo _app.js:

```
import './main.css'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />
  }
```

Que por sua vez estão todos na pasta pages:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ela nao executa meu alerta, que esta na function `funcao_click()`:

```
function funcao_click() {


    alert('VOCÊ CLICOU NA IMAGEM!');


        }
```

Não estou conseguindo fazer essa interação com JS,  como resolver isso?

Answer (score -1):

Uma das coisas, no React, consequentemente no Next também, algumas propriedades mudam de nome, como o class que vira className, onclick que vira onClick, e ao invés de onclick="função()" vc deve fazer onClick={() => função}
por exemplo:

```
export default function Home () {
  
  function funcao_click() {
    alert('VOCÊ CLICOU NA IMAGEM!');
  }

    return (
      <div className='v5_3' onClick={() => funcao_click}></div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).